# $mysqli->fetch_array(); returns weird results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm running into a very strange situation that I've never seen before. A simple SQL query in PHP using MySQLi isn't returning the correct column names when I fetch the array.

I've looked on php.net and here for a solution but all I've seen so far is the version of PHP and MySQL must be > 5 which they both are.

Here's a screenshot of Eclipse showing the SQL results being put into $row with incorrect column name. edi_packets_to_send is the table not the column name.

```
SELECT `id`,`times`, `send`, `no_of_attemps` from `edi_packets_to_send` WHERE `send` = 't' and `network_id`= 8012
```

[image]

The Table dump:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `edi_packets_to_send`;
CREATE TABLE `edi_packets_to_send` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `packet` char(83) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `send` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false',
  `seq` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `network_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `times` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `termostat_location` char(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `packet_type` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `no_of_attemps` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `network_network_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cms_room_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `action_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `network_id` (`network_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `network_network_id` (`network_network_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `room_id` (`cms_room_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=82 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `edi_packets_to_send` VALUES ('17', '02 07 00 01 ff 1f ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff', '111', 't', '', '8012', '2014-01-22 13:22:36', '0007', '1f', '1', '0', '37', '111');
INSERT INTO `edi_packets_to_send` VALUES ('18', '02 07 00 01 ff 32 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff', '112', 't', '', '8012', '2014-01-22 13:08:27', '0007', '32', '1', '0', '37', '18');
INSERT INTO `edi_packets_to_send` VALUES ('19', '02 07 00 01 ff 1e ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff', '113', 't', '', '8012', '2014-01-22 13:02:28', '0007', '1e', '1', '0', '37', '5');
```

The PHP test code:

```
<pre>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('log_errors', 'On');

define('DB1_HOSTNAME',      'localhost');
define('DB1_USERNAME',      'xxxx');
define('DB1_PASSWORD',      'xxxx');
define('DB1_DATABASE',      'xxxx');
define('DB1_PORT',          '3306');
define('DB1_DATABASE_DEBUG', true); 

try{
$sql_debug = '';

$idhotelu = "8012";

$mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB1_HOSTNAME, DB1_USERNAME, DB1_PASSWORD, DB1_DATABASE);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {throw new exception("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());}

$sql = "SELECT `id`,`times`, `send`, `no_of_attemps` from `edi_packets_to_send` WHERE `send` = 't' and `network_id`=".$idhotelu;
$sql_debug[] = __file__." (Line ".__line__."): ". $sql; 
if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)){throw new Exception("SQL Failed ".__file__." on line ".__line__.":\n".$sql);}

$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

print_r($row);



}catch(Exception $e){   
$sql_debug[] = "**Fatal: ".$e->getMessage();
if (DB1_DATABASE_DEBUG){ print_r($sql_debug);}
die();
}
```

Has this happened to anyone else?

---

I did find that my Eclipse PHP version is somewhat old, could this be the issue? and if so, how can I update my PHP version on eclipse ?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Does the `print_r` also yield incorrect results?

Comment: Yes it does, it's so strange!

Comment: I get this: Array
(
    [id] => 17
    [times] => 2014-01-22 13:22:36
    [edi_packets_to_send] => 1
)

Comment: Not only is the column name incorrect, you are also missing an entire column (`send` is gone). What if you run the query on you DB directly?

Comment: Try the query without the backticks.

Comment: Exactly, to make things even worse, if I add another column to select, I get the database's schema name...

Comment: @Bart Friederichs: tried that already, I added the backticks to be certain there wasn't a reserved keyword (like send). When I execute the query directly on MySQL the proper 3 rows with all columns are returned as expected.

Comment: I just tried on my local LAMP with the same table/data and code and var dump gives me array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "17" ["times"]=> string(19) "2014-01-22 13:22:36" ["send"]=> string(1) "t" ["no_of_attemps"]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: I'm using IIS7.5 along with MySQL - you think the php_mysqli.dll is the issue?

Comment: Not sure if thats an issue but ideally your query is getting data and they are rendered into the $row var in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was the old PHP version running on eclipse. **I upgraded to a higher version of PHP** and the results came back as expected !

[image]